# sparkSession/sparkContext can not get hadoop configuration

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I am running spark 2, hive, hadoop at local machine, and I want to use spark sql to read data from hive table.

It works all fine when I have hadoop running at default `hdfs://localhost:9000`, but if I change to a different port in core-site.xml:

```
<name>fs.defaultFS</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9099</value>
```

Running a simple sql `spark.sql("select * from archive.tcsv3 limit 100").show();` in spark-shell will give me the error:

```
ERROR metastore.RetryingHMSHandler: AlreadyExistsException(message:Database default already exists)
.....
From local/147.214.109.160 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused;
.....
```

I get the AlreadyExistsException before, which doesn't seem to influence the result.

I can make it work by creating a new sparkContext:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
sc.stop()
var sc = new SparkContext()
val session = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("test").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
session.sql("show tables").show()
```

My question is, why the initial sparkSession/sparkContext did not get the correct configuration? How can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Food for thought... Context was created prior and as it cannot be changed...

Answer (score 12):

If you are using `SparkSession` and you want to set configuration on the the spark context then use `session.sparkContext`

```
val session = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("test")
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()
import session.implicits._

session.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
```

You don't need to import `SparkContext` or created it before the `SparkSession`

Comment: Alternatively, you can also insert `.config()` into the builder method chain: `SparkSettion.builder().appName("app-name").config("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem").getOrCreate()` This is simpler than writing another statement. (I tested Apache Spark v2.4.3)